# What is the Applet replacement in .Net

Tags: .net, applet

What is the Applet replacement in .Net. If i would need to change the Stock Ticker Applet to a  .Net version, What technlogy should i suggest???

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Silverlight comes close. [This forum post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/798.aspx) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) is a flash like browser plugin which runs .Net code. Silverlight also runs on Linux and MacOSX. Another alternative is [XBAP](http://www.xbap.org/) but that only works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

activeX controls probably.

Answer (score -1):

You could build it as a custom/user control.